# DS160: consequences of answering NO to "Do you wish to provide information about your presence on any other websites"?

Tags: visas, us-visa

In the online US visa application form (DS160) there is the following question about social media presence:

> Do you wish to provide information about your presence on any other websites or applications you have used within the last five years to create or share content (photos, videos, status updates, etc.)?

It is worded as if it is up to the applicant to decide whether to provide this information or not. However, in the final review stage of this application form this question transforms into a different one with a significantly different meaning:

> Have you used additional social media platforms in the last five years?

To be on the safe side, it is obviously easier to just pretend that you wish to list all the social media accounts and then list them, but what if you actually do not wish to do so? Is it OK to answer "No" to the question above while having accounts in some additional social media platforms? What could be the consequences?

Upd: the question that precedes this one in the application form is as follows:

> Do you have a social media presence?

And it has a drop-down list with approx. 10 websites (facebook, linkedin, etc.)

Comment: I would answer no to the first, and yes to the second question.

Comment: What is the question which precedes the first one? It says "any *other* websites" so they must have already asked something.

Comment: @KristvanBesien I don't think it's two different questions: "in the final review stage of this application form this question transforms into a different one with a significantly different meaning."  The final review stage is where they show all of the questions with the answers you already gave, and if you want to change any of your answers there's a button taking you back.  I think they changed the question from "have you used..." to "do you wish..." but somehow neglected to update the wording in the final review.

Comment: @WeatherVane please see the update